# Java Play - How to query OneToMany Ebean

Tags: playframework, one-to-many, ebean

I have the following models:

> ```
> @Entity
>       @Table(name = "post")
>       public class Post extends Model {
>       @Id
>       @GeneratedValue
>       public Long id;
>       @Column(name = "url", nullable = false, length = 255)
>       public String url;
>       @Column(name = "content")
>       public String content;
>       @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "post")
>       public List comments;
>       [...]
>   
>   and
> ```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment extends Model {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long id;
@Column(name = "content", nullable = false, length = 255)
public String content;
@Column(name = "isDelete")
public boolean isDelete = false;
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Post post;
```

Then I try to do a search like:

```
 Post post = find.select("*").fetch("comments").where().eq("id", postId).eq("comments.isDelete", true).findUnique();
```

But That's not working
SQL query like :

return Post
SELECT * FROM POST p INNER JOIN COMMENT c
ON POST.ID=COMMENT.ID
WHERE p.id = ? 
AND c.isDelete = false;

How do i can use Ebean ? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your Post class:

```
public static Find<Long,Post> find = new Find<Long,Post>(){};
```

Add this to your Comment class:

```
public static Find<Long,Comment> find = new Find<Long,Comment>(){};
```

In your Post class is a little error in it, replace it like so:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "post")
    public List<Comment> comments;
```

Now you can query it like this:

```
Post post = Post.find.fetch("comment").where().eq("id", postId).eq("comment.isDelete", true).findUnique();
```

Now you can access the comments like so:

```
post.comments
```

or:

```
List<Comment> comments = post.comments;
```

You get the idea

Comment: thanks for answering but in my query
 `eq("comments.isDelete", true)`
That not working

Comment: thanks ALEX. But in Java code

`@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "post")
    public List<Comment> comments;`
So 
`fetch("comment")`
That not working. But I try writing
`Post post = find.fetch("comments").where().eq("id",postId).eq("t1.isDelete", false).findUnique();`
That ok but not good. 
p/s : Because I'm Japanese, so English was bad. So sorry

Comment: @RuaTahi Don't worry I understand you, you could try it from the other side ( comments ) like: List<Comment> comments = Comment.find.where().eq("postId", postId).eq("isDeleted", false).findList();